# How to fix column cannot be found on CellFormatting event?

Tags: c#, sql

[MY COLUMNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLOJ5.jpg)

[THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88beC.jpg)

i have this problem wherein my code cannot see the column named "SOA RECEIVED". Then I have this event called CellFormatting because i wanted to get and calculate the dates between the column "SOA RECEIVED" and "DATE PAID". My column is existing yet it cannot locate it. Its real column name from SQL is "SOA_RCV_DTE" then I just changed its name to "SOA RECEIVED". The columns also doesnt appear properly because of the error any ideas how to fix this?